# attaining 100% packet transmissions at high frequency

Tags: tinyos

Using the Oscilloscope file I am trying to sample at a rate of 10ms using tinyos with micaz motes.If I sample at 10ms which means I should get 100 packets/second,I get only 50 packets/second successfully received and displayed on the terminal window.To rectify this I went into the following directory:/tos/sensorboards/mts300 and opened the Accelp.nc file.The relevant part of code is as shown below:

```
async command uint8_t ConfigY.getRefVoltage() 
{
return ATM128_ADC_VREF_OFF;
}

async command uint8_t ConfigY.getPrescaler() {
return ATM128_ADC_PRESCALE_64;
}

command error_t SplitControl.start() {
call AccelPin.makeOutput();
call AccelPin.set();

call Timer.startOneShot(14); //orignally at 17ms
return SUCCESS; }
```

I changed the timer value to 14ms in the above code instead of the orignal 17ms.So this allowed me to get 100% packet efficiency that is 100 packets/second at a sampling rate of 10ms. But after doing this,I noticed that I was getting disturbance in the signal even when the accelerometer was completely still. Is there a way I can eliminate this disturbance and also get 100% packet transmissions and am I doing the right thing to get 100% transmission success? Changing the return value of pre-scalar does not seem to have much effect at all.

Comment: It seems that this particular sensor needs 17-milliseconds turn-on or settling time after being powered on. Making this delay smaller may lead to incorrect results as you experienced. The documentation of this accelerometer is here: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse466/07wi/labs/l3/567227477ADXL202E_a.pdf.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the limiting factor here.